# Generate highchart instance on floating div from mouseOver on axis label or from series point

Tags: highcharts

I've been looking for it on older forum posts or API but couldn't find any solution. I'm trying to show a new chart on `mouseOver/click` event from series point or axis labels, like a tooltip.
First I found some references to highslide, but I couldn't make it work on my project dependencies.
Than I tried using `mouseOver` from series points, but `e` listener don't return `screenX` or `screenY`, only click event listener does. So I found `custom-events.js` from black label, also no succes on mouseOver events. So I'm using click for now, now I'm also struggling to define diferent charts height. I'm setting it via `chart.height` but it seems to ignore it, I'm creating multiples charts on a page, calling the constructor from another js file.

Another idea was to plot a chart inside tooltip, but I couldn't find any demo or related topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at this example which shows how to render the chart as the outstanding HTML element in the tooltip.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p0mb65ef/

```
  tooltip: {
    useHTML: true,
    pointFormatter: function() {
      var data = [this.x, this.y, this.z];
      setTimeout(function() {
        Highcharts.chart('chart', {
          title: {
            text: ''
          },
          legend: {
            enabled: false
          },
          credits: {
            enabled: false
          },
          series: [{
            animation: false,
            data: data
          }],
          yAxis: {
            title: ''
          },
          xAxis: {
            categories: ['x', 'y', 'z']
          }
        })
      }, 10);
      return '<div id="chart" style="width: 100px; height: 150px;"></div>';
    }
  }
```